# reading from a csv file in java

Tags: java, csv

Hi everyone i am new to programming and I'm trying to read from a csv file and display the result on the monitor.The csv file contains a country name, year, and the stats of cellular data of each year. This is a snippet as the file contains 252 countries but decided to put 2 countries but here is a brief summary of the what the file contains:

```
World Development Indicators
Number of countries,252
Country Name,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012
Aruba,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.029310471,0,0,2.138784453,3.605985937,3.98141538,6.16435217,13.48254011,16.50927821,57.05427692,65.05605558,72.10431377,99.64250268,103.3849507,108.1325002,112.2180618,119.2038996,126.2103374,129.72824,0,131.8565401
Andorra,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.307211734,1.278625641,1.250259142,4.424155104,8.538444783,13.44671556,22.12730607,32.14530928,35.99902139,43.27794118,45.77115817,68.60251444,73.82494308,79.48487497,84.27763597,78.1171579,80.2836099,82.06181111,84.06818386,83.53432222,81.50204186
```

I have already created the cellularData file and tested it by manually hard copying the details of the file and putting it in a Test class and it worked. But now i have to read from the csv file and be able to do the same operations with my cellularData file. The TestCSVReader was provided and i am to follow the requirements of TestReaderCSV for my CSV class file. I am having trouble creating the csv class as i am new to programming and reading up on File IO. For my csv class it has the following attributes and methods:

Attributes:

Instance variable called “countryNames”, a one dimensional array of type String, which holds the names of all countries read from the CSV file.

Instance variable called “yearLabels”, a one dimensional array of type int, which holds the year number read from the CSV file.

Instance variable called “cellularDataTable”, a two dimensional array of type double, where the row represents a country, and the column represents the number of subscriptions for a specific year.

Methods:

A constructor that takes in the file name.
        We will use this to create a new File object and Scanner object.

Using the Scanner object, read the CSV file one line using “nextLine()”.

“getCountryNames” method which returns “countryNames”

“getYearLabels” method which returns “yearLabels”

“getParsedTable” which returns “cellularDataTable”

I have to ignore the first line of the csv file where is reads "world development indicators".  But read "Number of countries, 252". Since there are 252 to countries i have to parse it to an int. Read the CSV file one line at a time until you reach line starting with "Country Name".  The format of this line is:
            "Country Name, [year], [year]"
            where [year] is an integer, which we will use as the label for a year.
            For example:
            "Country Name,1960,1961,1962"

```
•    To Read the rest of the CSV file one line at a time.
        The format is:
        "[country name],[count1],[count2][count3]
         [country name],[count1],[count2][count3]
```

but having trouble and how to start. Here is a snippet of my csv class file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CSVReader {
String countryNames;
String[] country;
int yearLabels;
int[] yearNum;
double cellularDataTable;
double[][] tables;
Scanner scan;

public CSVReader(String file) throws IOException
{
    File data = new File(file);
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File doest not exist");

    countryNames="";

}
public String getCountryNames()
{
    return countryNames;
}
public int getYearLabels()
{
    return yearLabels;
}
public double getParsedTable()
{
    return cellularDataTable;
}
}
```

The TestCSVReader Below is my test file for CVS class as it also a guideline to my CSV class file.

```
/**
*  Tests the CSVReader class, which reads input from a CSV file. Uses
*  the attributes stored in CSVReader object to fill the CellularData class.
*/
public class TestCSVReader {

/**
 * Includes test examples for class CSVReader.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    final String FILENAME = "data/cellular.csv";    // Directory path for Mac OS X
    //final String FILENAME = "data\cellular.csv";  // Directory path for Windows OS (i.e. Operating System)


    CSVReader parser = new CSVReader(FILENAME);

    String [] countryNames = parser.getCountryNames();
    int [] yearLabels = parser.getYearLabels();
    double [][] parsedTable = parser.getParsedTable();      

    CellularData datatable;
    int numRows = parsedTable.length;
    int numColumns = parser.getNumberOfYears();
    int startingYear = yearLabels[0];
    datatable = new CellularData(numRows, numColumns, startingYear);


    for (int countryIndex = 0; countryIndex < countryNames.length; countryIndex++)
    {
        double [] countryData = parsedTable[countryIndex];
        datatable.addCountry(countryNames[countryIndex], countryData);                  
    }


    System.out.printf(countryNames[0] + " (1960 to 2012): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod(countryNames[0],1960,2012));
    // the output is: Aruba (1960 to 2012): 1170.50 

    System.out.printf(countryNames[100] + " (1960 to 2012): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod(countryNames[100],1960,2012));
    // the output is: Hungary (1960 to 2012): 1246.58 

    System.out.printf(countryNames[200] + " (1960 to 2012): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod(countryNames[200],1960,2012));
    // the output is: Singapore (1960 to 2012): 1582.80
    }
 }
```

Also here is my CellularData class file i created:

```
public class CellularData {

private Object [][]array;
private int year;

public CellularData(int rows, int columns, int year)
{
    array = new Object[rows+1][columns+1];  //add +1 because initializes the header.
    array[0][0] = "Country";
    this.year = year;
    for(int i=1;i<=columns;i++)
    {
    array[0][i] = year++;   //increments the year
    }
}

public void addCountry(String country, double []num)
{
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {    
    if(array[i][0] == null)     //checks if the first row is empty
    {
        addCountry(country, num, i);  //inserts the data 
        break;
    }
    }
}
private void addCountry(String country, double []num, int row)
{
    array[row][0] = country;
    for(int j = 1;j<array[row].length;j++)
    {
        array[row][j] = num[j-1];
    }
}
public double getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod(String country, int sYear, int eYear)
{
     double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (country.equalsIgnoreCase((String) array[i][0])) { //matches with the parameters passed ignoring CAPS
                int start = 1 + sYear - year;   //first index position of the year
                int end = start + (eYear - sYear);  //end position of the year

                if (start >= 0 && end < array[i].length) {   //checks to see if index position is out of bounds

                    for (int k = start; k <= end; k++) {
                        // System.out.println(">> " + country + " adding " + array[i][k]);
                        sum += (Double) array[i][k];   //sum of the stats
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //returns Error messgae and -1
                    System.out.println("ERROR : requested year "+sYear+" from "+ country+" is less than starting year "+this.year);
                    sum = -1;
                    }
            }
            }
    return sum;
    }

public String toString()
{ //prints the array.
    for(Object []a: array)
    {
        for(Object k:a)
        {
            System.out.print(k + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return " ";
    }

 }
```

Also this was the Test file i created for cellularData that worked just copied and pasted from csv file but now i need to read from the csv file itself:

```
public class TestCellularData {

public static void main(String []args)
{
    final double[] usaPartial = {0,0,0.14,.28,.5,.83,1.39};
    final double[] canadaPartial = {0,0,.05,.23,.37,.75,1.26};
    final double[] mexicoPartial = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0.01};

     int numRows = 3;
     int numColumns = canadaPartial.length;
     int startingYear = 1983;

    CellularData datatable = new CellularData(numRows, numColumns, startingYear);
    datatable.addCountry("USA", usaPartial);
    datatable.addCountry("Mexico", mexicoPartial);
    datatable.addCountry("Canada", canadaPartial);

    System.out.println(datatable);

    System.out.printf("usa (1983 to 1989): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod("usa",1983,1989));
    // country is "usa", subscriptions from 1983 to 1989
    // the output is: 
    // usa (1983 to 1989): 3.14
    System.out.printf("mexico (1983 to 1989): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod("mexico",1983,1989));
    // country is "mexico", subscriptions from 1960 to 2000
    // the output is:
    // mexico (1983 to 1989): 0.01                  
    // NOTE: in order to get this result, you must test beyond the sample data included here and refer to the CSV file.
    System.out.printf("canada (1890 to 2000): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod("canada",1890, 2000));
    // the output is:
    // ERROR : requested year 1890  is less than starting year 1893
    // canada (1890 to 2000): -1.00 

     // Part 2
    System.out.println("\n\nPart 2 with All Data:");
    final double[] CANADA = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.046433382,
            0.229211886,0.370663166,0.752880479,1.264765577,2.110674786,2.769888481,3.621301434,
            4.648371087,6.435664704,8.840378661,11.82226558,14.04583637,17.73689555,22.72196984,
            28.42909462,34.36625958,37.94941948,42.07126881,47.06386648,52.75959279,57.49320536,
            61.47310755,66.20487722,70.54830532,75.676078,79.41215888,80.05046389};
    final double[] MEXICO = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0.001815204,0.010079818,0.074266061,0.183067275,0.348322481,0.421293924,
            0.608553991,0.721767371,1.051320868,1.758956617,3.326889843,7.556565917,
            13.55289414,20.65462731,24.29476815,27.85371761,35.15321825,42.56115672,
            49.40875353,58.62729509,65.49948112,71.45817512,77.51826326,79.24118294,83.35070827};
    final double[] USA = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.038253436,0.140659444,
            0.279060364,0.498659917,0.829863407,1.39281703,2.075802366,2.939643902,4.249049037,
            6.103716586,9.104921407,12.6047249,16.23815248,20.14238484,24.89063952,30.57610298,
            38.46809105,44.69057874,48.85103822,54.84681409,62.54719598,68.31769507,76.29353842,
            82.06414479,85.20916517,88.62364611,91.31165202,94.71891668,95.44786574};

    startingYear = 1960;
    numRows = 3;
    numColumns = CANADA.length;

    datatable = new CellularData(numRows, numColumns, startingYear);

    datatable.addCountry("canada", CANADA);
    datatable.addCountry("mexico", MEXICO);
    datatable.addCountry("usa", USA);

    System.out.println(datatable);

    System.out.printf("usa (1983 to 1989): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod("mexico",1983,1989));
    System.out.printf("mexico (1960 to 2000): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod("mexico",1960,2000));
    System.out.printf("canada (1890 to 2000): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod("canada",1890, 2000));

}
}
```

Comment: Use an appropriate library like [openCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) as CSV is far more complex then you might first think...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it the OP hasn't made any effort to do research about this. Instead directly posting in SO for code help.

Comment: Just because a variable is declared as `final` doesn't mean, that it is a constant and should be written in uppercase. Please read the naming conventions for more information: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html